# Check if Enemies exist in the room with a WireCube

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i'm making a rogue-like game in 2D where you can go room to room. Doors opens when there is no enemies left in the room.

I don't want to check on the scene because their is multiple room by scene.

The first solution that came to my mind was to draw a WireCube the size of the room and check inside if `tag = "Enemy"` are found. if not i'll just open the doors.

But i can't find the right way to wrote it and haven't found any topic on this matter.

Thanks to everyone that can help me on that !

This is the start of the script but i can't figure out what to write inside the update method.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomClean : MonoBehaviour
{

    void Start()
    {
        foes = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        // Draw a yellow cube at the transform position
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, new Vector3(50, 50, 50));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can enemies move between rooms?  If not, when you instantiate them, store their assigned room in a script (ie. EnemyLocation.cs) and then check each enemy against the room.  Or, go the other way and add a script to the room with an array of enemies that have been assigned to it and check each enemy in that array to see if any are still alive.

Comment: I'm not sure how the `DrawWireCube` is supposed to be related to your checks, but the physics equivalent would be `Physics.OverlapBox`: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapBox.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers ! 
No they stay in the room so i think i'm gonna try to do it like you say, instantiate them with the room as a parent and then check if they still exist in the room when you destroy (kill) them.

Thanks again !